# How to inject external input into a SlimerJS script dynamically?

Tags: javascript, casperjs, slimerjs

I need some help with SlimerJS. Basically my program needs to take input from stdin periodically to do the next task.

The following code works well with PhantomJS+CasperJS in case of reading from an external input, but fails to do the same in SlimerJS+CasperJS.

```
some code ...

var nextLink = system.stdin.readLine();

some code ...
```

Any thoughts about how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

This simply isn't supported as evident by the [feature request on GitHub](https://github.com/laurentj/slimerjs/issues/188) and lack of `stdin` property in the [documentation](http://docs.slimerjs.org/current/api/system.html).

There are mainly two workarounds possible. Both of the require that you write a second program in the language of your choice (can be a PhantomJS script).

1. When you come to the point in the CasperJS script where it is necessary to get input, you read a predefined file multiple times until something is inside it. So you execute the second program when you see that CasperJS is at this point. The program may be a simple command like

   ```
   echo my text > predefinedFile.txt
   ```

   or something more elaborate. The polling functions in CasperJS would be something like this:

   ```
   function poll(){
       var content = fs.read(predefinedFile).trim();
       if (!content) {
           this.wait(1000, poll);
       } else {
           // do something sensible
       }
   }
   //....
   casper.then(poll);
   ```
2. There is a [webserver module](http://docs.slimerjs.org/current/api/webserver.html) that you can use to send messages to SlimerJS when it is running as a CasperJS script. The second program would need to send actual requests.